# The second jquery plugin not working online but in localhost works

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

The index page of my website has two jquery pluggins.The second plugin located below the first banner plugin doesn't work(move) when uploaded to the live server.However in the localhost it works. I wonder why?

banner.php(first plugin)

```
    <?php require_once('Connections/wedding_conn.php'); ?>
<?php
mysql_select_db($database_wedding_conn, $wedding_conn);
$query_RecBanner = "SELECT * FROM tbl_bannerstore WHERE banner_status = 1";
$RecBanner = mysql_query($query_RecBanner, $wedding_conn) or die(mysql_error());

$totalRows_RecBanner = mysql_num_rows($RecBanner);
?>
    <!-- it works the same with all jquery version from 1.x to 2.x -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.9.1.min.js">
    </script>
    <!-- use jssor.slider.mini.js (40KB) or jssor.sliderc.mini.js (32KB, with caption, no slideshow) or jssor.sliders.mini.js (28KB, no caption, no slideshow) instead for release -->
    <!-- jssor.slider.mini.js = jssor.sliderc.mini.js = jssor.sliders.mini.js = (jssor.core.js + jssor.utils.js + jssor.slider.js) -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jssor.core.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jssor.utils.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jssor.slider.js"></script>
    <script>

        jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {

            var _SlideshowTransitions = [
            //Fade
            { $Duration: 1200, $Opacity: 2 }
            ];

            var options = {
                $AutoPlay: true,                                    //[Optional] Whether to auto play, to enable slideshow, this option must be set to true, default value is false
                $AutoPlaySteps: 1,                                  //[Optional] Steps to go for each navigation request (this options applys only when slideshow disabled), the default value is 1
                $AutoPlayInterval: 3000,                            //[Optional] Interval (in milliseconds) to go for next slide since the previous stopped if the slider is auto playing, default value is 3000
                $PauseOnHover: 1,                               //[Optional] Whether to pause when mouse over if a slider is auto playing, 0 no pause, 1 pause for desktop, 2 pause for touch device, 3 pause for desktop and touch device, 4 freeze for desktop, 8 freeze for touch device, 12 freeze for desktop and touch device, default value is 1

                $ArrowKeyNavigation: true,                          //[Optional] Allows keyboard (arrow key) navigation or not, default value is false
                $SlideDuration: 500,                                //[Optional] Specifies default duration (swipe) for slide in milliseconds, default value is 500
                $MinDragOffsetToSlide: 20,                          //[Optional] Minimum drag offset to trigger slide , default value is 20
                //$SlideWidth: 600,                                 //[Optional] Width of every slide in pixels, default value is width of 'slides' container
                //$SlideHeight: 300,                                //[Optional] Height of every slide in pixels, default value is height of 'slides' container
                $SlideSpacing: 0,                                   //[Optional] Space between each slide in pixels, default value is 0
                $DisplayPieces: 1,                                  //[Optional] Number of pieces to display (the slideshow would be disabled if the value is set to greater than 1), the default value is 1
                $ParkingPosition: 0,                                //[Optional] The offset position to park slide (this options applys only when slideshow disabled), default value is 0.
                $UISearchMode: 1,                                   //[Optional] The way (0 parellel, 1 recursive, default value is 1) to search UI components (slides container, loading screen, navigator container, arrow navigator container, thumbnail navigator container etc).
                $PlayOrientation: 1,                                //[Optional] Orientation to play slide (for auto play, navigation), 1 horizental, 2 vertical, 5 horizental reverse, 6 vertical reverse, default value is 1
                $DragOrientation: 3,                                //[Optional] Orientation to drag slide, 0 no drag, 1 horizental, 2 vertical, 3 either, default value is 1 (Note that the $DragOrientation should be the same as $PlayOrientation when $DisplayPieces is greater than 1, or parking position is not 0)

                $SlideshowOptions: {                                //[Optional] Options to specify and enable slideshow or not
                    $Class: $JssorSlideshowRunner$,                 //[Required] Class to create instance of slideshow
                    $Transitions: _SlideshowTransitions,            //[Required] An array of slideshow transitions to play slideshow
                    $TransitionsOrder: 1,                           //[Optional] The way to choose transition to play slide, 1 Sequence, 0 Random
                    $ShowLink: true                                    //[Optional] Whether to bring slide link on top of the slider when slideshow is running, default value is false
                },

                $BulletNavigatorOptions: {                                //[Optional] Options to specify and enable navigator or not
                    $Class: $JssorBulletNavigator$,                       //[Required] Class to create navigator instance
                    $ChanceToShow: 2,                               //[Required] 0 Never, 1 Mouse Over, 2 Always
                    $AutoCenter: 1,                                 //[Optional] Auto center navigator in parent container, 0 None, 1 Horizontal, 2 Vertical, 3 Both, default value is 0
                    $Steps: 1,                                      //[Optional] Steps to go for each navigation request, default value is 1
                    $Lanes: 1,                                      //[Optional] Specify lanes to arrange items, default value is 1
                    $SpacingX: 10,                                   //[Optional] Horizontal space between each item in pixel, default value is 0
                    $SpacingY: 10,                                   //[Optional] Vertical space between each item in pixel, default value is 0
                    $Orientation: 1                                 //[Optional] The orientation of the navigator, 1 horizontal, 2 vertical, default value is 1
                },

                $ArrowNavigatorOptions: {
                    $Class: $JssorArrowNavigator$,              //[Requried] Class to create arrow navigator instance
                    $ChanceToShow: 2,                               //[Required] 0 Never, 1 Mouse Over, 2 Always
                    $Steps: 1                                       //[Optional] Steps to go for each navigation request, default value is 1
                }
            };
            var jssor_slider1 = new $JssorSlider$("slider1_container", options);

            //responsive code begin
            //you can remove responsive code if you don't want the slider scales while window resizes
            function ScaleSlider() {
                var parentWidth = jssor_slider1.$Elmt.parentNode.clientWidth;
                if (parentWidth)
                    jssor_slider1.$ScaleWidth(Math.min(parentWidth, 960));
                else
                    window.setTimeout(ScaleSlider, 30);
            }

            ScaleSlider();

            $(window).bind("load", ScaleSlider);
            $(window).bind("resize", ScaleSlider);
            $(window).bind("orientationchange", ScaleSlider);
            //responsive code end
        });
    </script>
    <!-- Jssor Slider Begin -->
    <!-- You can move inline styles to css file or css block. -->
    <div id="slider1_container" style="position: relative; top: 0px; left: 0px; width: 960px; height: 530px; overflow: hidden; ">

        <!-- Loading Screen -->
        <div u="loading" style="position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px;">
            <div style="filter: alpha(opacity=70); opacity:0.7; position: absolute; display: block;
                background-color: #000000; top: 0px; left: 0px;width: 100%;height:100%;">
            </div>
            <div style="position: absolute; display: block; background: url(img/loading.gif) no-repeat center center;
                top: 0px; left: 0px;width: 100%;height:100%;">
            </div>
        </div>

        <!-- Slides Container -->
        <div u="slides" style="cursor: move; position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; width: 960px; height: 530px; overflow: hidden;">
        <?php
        while($row_RecBanner = mysql_fetch_assoc($RecBanner)){
            if(($row_RecBanner['banner_id'])!=0)
            {
        ?>

            <div>


                <img u="image" src="banner_online_store/<?php echo $row_RecBanner['banner_img']; ?>" />

            </div>
            <?php
        }}
            ?>


        </div>

        <!-- Bullet Navigator Skin Begin -->
        <style>
            /* jssor slider bullet navigator skin 05 css */
            /*
            .jssorb05 div           (normal)
            .jssorb05 div:hover     (normal mouseover)
            .jssorb05 .av           (active)
            .jssorb05 .av:hover     (active mouseover)
            .jssorb05 .dn           (mousedown)
            */
            .jssorb05 div, .jssorb05 div:hover, .jssorb05 .av {
                background: url(img/b21.png) no-repeat;
                overflow: hidden;
                cursor: pointer;
            }

            .jssorb05 div {
                background-position: -7px -7px;
            }

                .jssorb05 div:hover, .jssorb05 .av:hover {
                    background-position: -37px -7px;
                }

            .jssorb05 .av {
                background-position: -67px -7px;
            }

            .jssorb05 .dn, .jssorb05 .dn:hover {
                background-position: -97px -7px;
            }
        </style>
        <!-- bullet navigator container -->
        <div u="navigator" class="jssorb05" style="position: absolute; bottom: 16px; right: 6px;">
            <!-- bullet navigator item prototype -->
            <div u="prototype" style="POSITION: absolute; WIDTH: 16px; HEIGHT: 16px;"></div>
        </div>
        <!-- Bullet Navigator Skin End -->
        <!-- Arrow Navigator Skin Begin -->
        <style>
            /* jssor slider arrow navigator skin 12 css */
            /*
            .jssora12l              (normal)
            .jssora12r              (normal)
            .jssora12l:hover        (normal mouseover)
            .jssora12r:hover        (normal mouseover)
            .jssora12ldn            (mousedown)
            .jssora12rdn            (mousedown)
            */
            .jssora12l, .jssora12r, .jssora12ldn, .jssora12rdn {
                position: absolute;
                cursor: pointer;
                display: block;
                background: url(img/test_1.png) no-repeat;
                overflow: hidden;
            }

            .jssora12l {
                background-position: -10px -25px;
            }

            .jssora12r {
                background-position: -72px -25px;
            }

            .jssora12l:hover {
                background-position: -260px -25px;
            }

            .jssora12r:hover {
                background-position: -331px -25px;
            }

            .jssora12ldn {
                background-position: -260px -25px;
            }

            .jssora12rdn {
                background-position: -331px -25px;
            }
        </style>
        <!-- Arrow Left -->
        <span u="arrowleft" class="jssora12l" style="width: 50px; height: 55px; top: 230px; left: 0px;">
        </span>
        <!-- Arrow Right -->
        <span u="arrowright" class="jssora12r" style="width: 50px; height: 55px; top: 230px; right: 0px">
        </span>
        <!-- Arrow Navigator Skin End -->
        <a style="display: none" href="http://www.jssor.com">responsive carousel</a>
    </div>
    <!-- Jssor Slider End -->
```

featured.php (second plugin which is not working)

```
 <?php require_once('Connections/wedding_conn.php'); ?>
<?php
mysql_select_db($database_wedding_conn, $wedding_conn);
$query_feature="SELECT tbl_productscontents.*,tbl_productsgallery.*,tbl_productscategory.*,tbl_subcategory.* FROM tbl_productscontents,tbl_productsgallery,tbl_productscategory,tbl_subcategory WHERE tbl_productscontents.pc_id=tbl_productscategory.pc_id AND
tbl_productscontents.productid=tbl_productsgallery.productid AND tbl_productscontents.productfeature='yes' AND tbl_subcategory.sub_id=tbl_productscontents.sub_id";
$result_feature=mysql_query($query_feature)or die(mysql_error());
?>
    <link href="themes/generic.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="themes/1/slider.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script src="themes/1/thumbnail-slider.js" type="text/javascript"></script>


    <span style="margin-top:25px;"><h1>Featured Products</h1></span>
    <div class="div2"> 

        <div id="mcts1">
         <?php
          while($row_feature=mysql_fetch_array($result_feature))
          {

          ?> 
            <table>
            <tr>
            <td>

            <a href="view_featured.php?id=<?php echo $row_feature['productid'];?>&cat_id=<?php echo $row_feature['pc_id']; ?>"><img class="class1" src="productshow/images/gallery/<?php echo $row_feature['pc_name'];?>/<?php echo $row_feature['sub_name'];?>/<?php echo $row_feature['ga_photo'];?>"/></a>
            </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
            <td>
           <a href="view_featured.php?id=<?php echo $row_feature['productid'];?>&cat_id=<?php echo $row_feature['pc_id']; ?>"><?php echo $row_feature['productname'];?></a>
            </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
            <td>
            <?php
                                if($_SESSION['mem_type']==1)
                                {
                                    if(isset($row_feature['productsales']))
                                    {
                                $p_price=$row_feature['productsales'];
                                    }
                                    else
                                    {
                                        $p_price=$row_feature['productprice'];
                                    }

                                ?>

                              <span class="cut">RM <?php echo number_format($row_feature['productprice'],2,'.','');?></span><br/>

                                <strong>RM <?php echo number_format($p_price,2,'.',''); ?></strong>
                               <?php
                                }
                                else if($_SESSION['mem_type']==2)
                                {
                                    $p_price=$row_feature['productprice']-$row_feature['discounted_price'];
                               ?>
                               <span class="cut">RM <?php echo number_format($row_feature['productprice'],2,'.','');?></span><br/>
                                <strong>RM <?php echo number_format($p_price,2,'.',''); ?></strong>
                               <?php
                                }else
                                {
                                 if(isset($row_feature['productsales']))
                                    {
                                $p_price=$row_feature['productsales'];
                                    }
                                    else
                                    {
                                        $p_price=$row_feature['productprice'];
                                    }

                               ?>   
                                 <span class="cut">RM <?php echo number_format($row_feature['productprice'],2,'.','');?></span><br/>
                                <strong>RM <?php echo number_format($p_price,2,'.',''); ?></strong>
                                <?php
                                }
                                ?>
            </td>
            </tr>
            </table>

            <?php
        }
        ?>

        </div>
    </div>
```

index.php(which include both first and second plugin)

```
    <?php
session_start();
?>
<?php require_once('Connections/wedding_conn.php'); ?>
<?php
mysql_select_db($database_wedding_conn, $wedding_conn);
$query_RecTitle = "SELECT * FROM tbl_content WHERE OID = 1";
$RecTitle = mysql_query($query_RecTitle) or die(mysql_error());
$row_RecTitle = mysql_fetch_assoc($RecTitle);
$totalRows_RecTitle = mysql_num_rows($RecTitle);

mysql_select_db($database_wedding_conn, $wedding_conn);
$query_RecWebConfig = "SELECT config_title FROM tbl_webconfig";
$RecWebConfig = mysql_query($query_RecWebConfig) or die(mysql_error());
$row_RecWebConfig = mysql_fetch_assoc($RecWebConfig);
$totalRows_RecWebConfig = mysql_num_rows($RecWebConfig);


?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title><?php echo $row_RecWebConfig['config_title']; ?> - Home</title>
<link rel="stylesheet"  type="text/css" href="style.css"/>

</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
      <div class="header">
        <table class="tab1">
          <tr>
          <td width="700">
          <a href="index.php"><div class="logo">

          </div></a>
          </td>
          <td valign="top">
          <div >
          <div class="socialmedia">

           <table>
             <tr>
           <!--  <td ><span class="follow">Follow us on</span> </td>-->
               <td>
                <a href="#"><img src="icons/fb.png" /></a>
                <a href="#"><img src="icons/g.png" /></a>
                <a href="#"><img src="icons/tw.png" /></a>
               </td><br />
            </tr>
          </table> 
         </div>

           <div>
            <?php
             include'search.php';
            ?>
          </div> 
          </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
          <td width="700"></td>
          <td>
         <div class="login">
        <?php
         include 'login_link.php';

         ?>
         </div>  

          </div>
          </td>
          </tr>



          <tr>

          <td width="700">
            <?php
            include'menu.php';
            ?>
          </td>
          <td>
          <div>
          <?php
           include'shop.php';
          ?>
          </div>
          </td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </div>
      <div class="banner">
      <?php
        include'banner.php';
      ?>
      </div>




      <div class="featured">

      <?php include 'featured.php'; ?>
      </div>
      <div class="cat">

      <?php
      include 'cat.php';
      ?>

      </div>

       <div class="footer">
       <?php
       include'footer.php';
       ?>
      </div>

  </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you describe what you mean by "not working"?

Comment: It's not working in the sense of the pictures inside the plugin doesn't move. It's a thumnail slider plugin from mootool.It will have an arrow om the left and on the right so that we can slide the pictures to the left and right.But now the arrows are not displaying so unable to slide.

Comment: Do you have a link to it online anywhere? The two most probable issues are that one or more JS or CSS file was not uploaded or not uploaded to the right place, -OR-, there is another JS error somewhere up the chain that is preventing this code from being run.

Comment: Please post a screenshot of your html from top to bottom.

Comment: @KyleEmmanuel, I've posted html of the index page from top to bottom.

Comment: @veronicageorge where do you place your included javascript files? in footer.php?

Comment: @veronicageorge the main rotating image is rotating for me, with left/right arrows... ? the photos of sprinklers. For Featured Products, all HTML is visible on screen (there's nothing left/right to move?)

Comment: @KyleEmmanuel, sorry I included them in banner.php and featured.php respectively. Now I've posted the full set of jquery for both pages. Please have  a look.

Comment: @SetSailMedia, The main one is working finely but the second one under the featured products which is not working and  they should slide to the left automatically not stand still. Even the arrow on the left and right also not appearing online.

Comment: It seems to be working fine for me although you REALLY need to compress some of the images down. No one will be able to use the site with a 20-30sec load time. This could also be making things seem like they are not working because it takes so long for the page to load. http://gtmetrix.com/reports/www.icherrytech.com/ft5wdJvZ

Comment: @veronicageorge - Ecommerce sites should load in 3 seconds or less. Anything over 3 seconds will see a dramatic drop in conversion. Lowering you page load times will give you an infinite increase in conversion (and sales) over worrying about getting a slider working.

Comment: @JoeConlin, is the thumnail slider working for you? And can you tell me how to adjust the page load time please?

Comment: @veronicageorge The large slider is working. The thumbs are NOT in a slider although I see no js errors so maybe there need to be more elements?? Not sure. In regards to optimizing page load time, use gtmetrix.com for analysis and then address the issues. The biggest impact will be to compress the images WAY down (this can be done without losing quality) and then adding caching to your htaccess file although there are plenty of thing you can do that it will tell you. I do optimization professionally and I use this as one of the tools to get a good idea of what's wrong quickly.

Comment: @JoeConlin, thank you for telling me about optimization , I will have to study on it. The thumbs are actually in a slider but it's not working online. I'm trying to fix it.

Comment: @veronicageorge You are already loading the jQuery library, why not just use a jQuery plugin for the sliders? Might be easier.

Comment: @JoeConlin, sorry I don't get you. I am using a plugin for the slider :(

Comment: Dear all , I think I found the reason.  I was actually using http://www.menucool.com/jquery-slider.Sadly it says in order to work on internet must buy the license.

Answer (score 0):

I think I found the reason. I was actually using menucool.com/jquery-slider.Sadly it says in order to work on internet must buy the license